# Android ActivityManager: am: not found (file not in /system/bin)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm working in eclipse and trying to use my phone (HTC Thunderbolt) for development for the first time (because the emulator is too slow).

In Eclipse I get the error:
Android ActivityManager: am: not found
(The error is after Android Launch!, adb is running normally, and Success!, etc.)

Using adb shell, I see that the am file is not located in /system/bin or anywhere else that I looked. I'm running a custom ROM on my phone. Is it possible the file is simply not present? If so, can I push it to my phone? How?

Thank you

EDIT: Using adb shell, from /, I ran ls -R | grep "^am$" and there is no file named "am".

I have seen posts like this [one](http://www.apad.tv/apadforum/showthread.php?1280-Solved-system-bin-sh-am-not-found-and-system-bin-sh-pm-not-found) where they mention an error message like system-bin-sh-am-not-found, but in those cases the file is actually present and needs to be edited. In my case, the file is not present. Anyone have a copy of /system/bin/am for Gingerbread? Is it the same for all devices?

Comment: Please see if [this is of any help](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/lithiummod/51568-6-14-rom-froyo-kangerade-v1-0-blazing-fast-7-theme-options-many-extras-80.html#post598233)

Comment: @Reno - thanks, but I read that whole page and did not see anything relevant. Which part did you think might help? My problem is that the /system/bin/am file is not physically on my phone. The file is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the custom ROM I was running. The ROM cook had not included that file in the ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your bin folder, there should be a file named after your project followed by .apk

example. project name = mountainx, the file is mountainx.apk

copy that into your handphone storage, then install it from your phone via application installer or any other applications that can access the apk file

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I find it confusing. Does your reply have anything to do with the "am" file (ActivityManager) or my question? I know how to install an .apk file. But I want to develop on my phone instead of the emulator.